# Drawing bezier curves with more than 3 control points

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, bezier

I know I can draw a bezier curve with 3 control points using bezierCurveTo().
How can I draw a bezier curve with more than 3 control points ? I tried using spline from KineticJS(since i can specify as many points as I want) but the resulting curve doesn't look like a bezier curve(if, for example, i set only 3 points). Can I somehow connect more quadratic bezier curves together to get a curve with more than 3 control points ?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle (at jsfiddle.net) with some code and I'll try and help you out?

Comment: also, have you seen: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-curves-with-anchor-points-using-kineticjs/

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have 3 curves:

```
 curve1, curve2, and curve3
```

and you want a curve which connects all the curves together, call it:

```
 curve 4
```

With kineticJS (4.3.1 at this time), you can do:

```
 var points1 = curve1.getPoints();
 var points2 = curve2.getPoints();
 var points3 = curve2.getPoints();
 var joined = points1.concat(points2,points3);

 curve4.setPoints(joined);
 // make sure to redraw the layer
```